# wp-admin/admin-ajax.php - Blocked due to other 4xx issue

Tags: wordpress

I am Doris, I am not from a developer background. I got a problem to ask. In the coverage section of the search console, I got this error wp-admin/admin-ajax.php is blocked due to other 4xx issue. After I explore more, I found /ajax/subscriptions/subscribe and /wp-json/elementskit/v1/ are some files that showing 404 error. Can someone help me to understand how I can resolve this?

Comment: If you're using any security plugin then those request urls might be getting blocked by the plugin, you can check the plugin documentation and see if they have any option to whitelist a url/path.